# Rails: using validation for user register/login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, user-registration

I have a simple User class with the following validation of name uniqueness:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :uniqueness => true,
```

It works great when a new user is created. However, when I check the login form, the user enters his name, and the system says it's already taken which doesn't make any sense.

So I implemented a separate `valid_login?` method, however I can't turn that unqueness check there:

```
def valid_login?
  validates :name, :uniqueness => false # doesn't work
end
```

This is my controller's code:

```
def login
    return unless request.post?

    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.valid_login?
      # Redirect to user's page
    end
end
```

I'm using my own authentication system which is quite simple: I store user's ID + password's hash in the cookies.

How can I turn of certain validation when I don't need it?

Comment: That's not the expected behavior. What does your login controller look like?

Comment: Also do you use a gem to manage logins/sessions? restful authentication, devise, authlogic, or did you hand roll your own login system?

Comment: Jordan & Brett, I've updated the question.

Comment: And regarding the unexpected behavior... What's unusual about it? I want to keep my code DRY and not to do the same validation for both registering a user and logging him in (such as making sure the username was entered etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with the :if/:unless parameters.